# How to use TWIG PATH helper inside my PHP classes?

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I have a class like below and I would like to output some texts and links when I call `Display` in my view file and right now it is working fine.

The problem is how to call the Twig PATH helper or any PHP equivalent to get route from any route name in my PHP classes;

```
myClass 
{
    // Other Code

    function Display($depth)
    {
        echo "<div class=\"heirarchy\">";

        for($i = 0; $i < $depth; $i++)
        {
            echo '&nbsp;';
        }

        echo "<a href=\"path('path_name')\" ".$this->description."</a>";

        if($this->isLeaf())
        {
            echo ' (Task)';
        }

        echo "</div>";

        foreach($this->children as $key => $value)
        {
            $value->Display($depth + 2);
        }

    }

}
```

Since this function is recursive I have no idea how to implement it in a twig function.

In other words, how can I get a route path from a route name in my classes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The router's `generate()` method is similar to Twig's `path()`, it generates an URL from a route's name.

Simply pass `$this->get('router')` from your controller to your class, and use it like this:

`$router->generate('my_route')`.

Also, I don't see the point of using this pseudo-OO class (with HTML inside of it).
You can use a template for this purpose.